# const value in for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, constants

I have seen code like,

**Approach 1**

```
for(int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
    do_some_stuff(i);
}
```

**Approach 2**

```
const int max_limit = 200;
for(int i = 0; i < max_limit; ++i) {
    do_some_stuff(i);
}
```

Is there any advantage for `Approach 2` over `Approach 1`?

Comment: IMO approach 1 is better as it is easier to read

Comment: Objectively speaking in your example: no. You will only get answers like "IMO...", "I think ... looks better' and so on - just a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally good practice to replace an integer constant by something with a meaningful name, so I'd say that's the main advantage of the second one. However, if the code is really simple than the extra line may just make it one more line to parse.

That said, if you are replacing something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < something.size(); ++i) {
    do_some_stuff(i);
}
```

with

```
const int something_sz = something.size();
for(int i = 0; i < something_sz; ++i) {
    do_some_stuff(i);
}
```

then there is the added benefit that it makes it obvious to the reader, as well as the compiler, that `something.size()` isn't changed by the call to `do_some_stuff(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use of magic numbers, such as `200` in your example, anywhere in your code is cause for concern. It makes the code harder to understand and maintain.

Approach 2 is better if the variable is appropriately named. `max_limit` has no more meaning than `200`. However, if you use `max_number_of_books`, it is a lot more meaningful than `200`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, approach 2 is better, when you define a const like `const int max_num_of_students` it looks more meaningful and someone reading to that code, can easily understand what is going on.

Another advantage of using such `const` in loops is that if you are printing names of students more than one time, you don't need to change the condition in your loop every time the count of students gets increased. Go to your variable and change it to new student count.

Answer (score 0):

Approach 2 is better as per my opinion.

1. **Readability** is enhanced.

   For example:

   ```
   int currentPortNo=getPortNo();
   const int inputPort=80;

   if(currentPortNo == inputPort){
   //Get input from port
   }
   ```

   when compared to:

   ```
   int currentPortNo=getPortNo();

   if(currentPortNo == 80){
   //Get input from port
   }
   ```
2. **Maintainability** is enhanced since if we want `inputPort` should be initialized(changed) with `81` instead of `80` due to new requirements/limitations we can simply use:

   ```
   const int inputPort=81;
   ```

   instead of changing all the occasion wherever the value `80` is used in entire program.
3. Also, if you need to pass a **pointer** around the program.
4. Can have the **scoping** and **typing** properties

Answer (score 0):

We should avoid to using the `magic number` anytime when wrote codes. Because if you use the number `200` only, maybe others cannot understand your codes' intention well. But when you use `const int max_limit = 200;`, we can understand the number `200`'s meanings. Especially when your codes was very complex, you must write it with the second way.

Answer (score 0):

2nd Approach is better as by this you can also get the value from the user:

```
cin>>max_limit;
```